# Is this a secure way to protect passwords when they must be in plaintext?

Tags: passwords, web-application

I am building a web app which will use my school's online grade reporting system. Students will sign in to my app using their credentials for the grade website. However, it does not provide an API, which means that my web app will have to store each user's password to get access to their grade data or force each user to log in every time my app needs access. The web app will need to be able to verify the data from the grade reporting website, so the server will need to log in, which means that the plaintext password will at some point have to be on the server.

My solution is to have each user's login details be stored locally in plaintext, then have the client send the credentials to the server whenever the server needs access to the grade system. The server would use the credentials to log in, then delete them. Everything uses HTTPS.

I believe that this system is secure because the plaintext passwords are on the server for only a short time and an attacker would not be able to access data stored on the client (assuming my web app is not vulnerable to XSS).

I'm planning to create the server in NodeJS and run it on a VPS.

Is this system secure? If not, what possible attacks exist and how could I prevent them?

Answer (score 3):

TLDR: No

Storing privacy sensitive information in plaintext should immediately ring the alarmbel in your security brain. Having a password stored in a plaintext means that all the attacker needs to do is obtain access to that plaintext, and voila, he has the password. Obtaining access to the file containing the passwords can happen via various attacks, depending on how you architecture looks like. Given that you are building most things up from scratch (and assuming your budget is rather minimal) it will be extremely hard, if not impossible, for you to defend against all possible attacks that may exist to obtain access to your password file. Even though they are only stored for a very short time, an attacker can sniff on network traffic and hence time when to attack based on user activity.

Additionally, having privacy sensitive information stored in plaintext means that you have to trust every person involved in the creation of your web app, as they might have credentials to access the server where the password file is stored.

Answer (score 2):

From your perspective it seems secure. However, as an end-user I would be very worried about trusting a new web app with the password I use on the school system.

Consider instead the OAuth2.0 protocol, or the OpenID Connect protocol. The school system will need to be set up as an Identity Provider, and provide APIs to allow your web app to retrieve data from their system. When the school system supports this, it will allow students to grant your web app access to the school system without them sharing their passwords with you. You may have seen many websites feature a 'Sign in with Google' button. Your app would have a 'Sign in with School' button.

Alternatively, your web app could run on the same system as the school's. You will be able to use the existing authentication mechanism, while being able to access student information directly from the backend.

Answer (score 0):

Don't store passwords as plain text. Instead, store a value derived from the password. E.g. store value produced by methods like argon2 or bcrypt. Then even if smb. gets access to these values, there will be no way to restore the passwords.

Comment: This seems to completely ignore the scenario outlined by the OP (access to the cleartext-password is required at some point).